# Change default browser in Word

Tags: internet-explorer, ms-word

I am developing a Word add-in using Angular. It opens by default in Internet Explorer inside Word.

Is it possible to change the default browser of Word from IE to another one?

I tried changing the settings in Windows (Control Panel -> Programs -> Default applications) but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you specify more what exactly you do?

Comment: If you want to stop Microsoft Internet Explorer (IE) from opening documents in the IE window instead of using the document's regular application then follow this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/162059/how-to-configure-internet-explorer-to-open-office-documents-in-the-app

Look for the "Let me fix it myself" section on this page.

Comment: Please take a look at the screenshot: https://ibb.co/krL4jv (sorry for Polish). It is a message displayed right after starting Philynx that informs about problems with the certificate. This whole message is displayed in a built-in browser (Internet Explorer). I am wondering if it is possible to change the default browser to a different one? (e.g. Chrome)